# Databinding to an Object with a property that's a string array

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, linq, repeater

I can't seem to figure out how to get the actual value with a repeater.  The data is there but it just displays a bunch of System.String[] as the value in the repeater.  Basically, I have a NewsItem object.  In the NewsItem object there is a field called tags.  In the tags there is an array of strings for the tags.  I'm trying to create a tag cloud based on all of the newsitems returned. I'm able to get data to the repeater, I just can't seem to figure out what data is coming. Any direction would be appreciated.  I've been googling for hours.

repeater datasource:

```
rptTagCloud.DataSource = allnewsitems.Select(x => x.NewsItemTags).Distinct();
```

in repeater: `<%# Container.DataItem %`>

Comment: what is allnewsitems ?

Comment: I'm guessing that `x.NewsItemTags` is an array of strings and you can easily solve it through `SelectMany()` --> `rptTagCloud.DataSource = allnewsitems.SelectMany(x => x.NewsItemTags).Distinct();`

Comment: You are the Angel of Mercy Silvermind!  Thank you.  What does that do exactly?  I'm assuming it selects all of the strings in the array, vs what it was doing which was selecting the default one??

Comment: Silvermind solved it. Shujaat, allnewsitems in an IEnumerable<NewsItem> which an object of various news article related properties.